# No CORS Headers set when HttpCode 500 is returned

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making an API that can be called from any origin using .net core MVC6... the issue i'm having is I can't seem to allow any origin, i'm able to get it to work for one origin no issue but when i set it to allow any origin it does not work.

What I have is -

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        ect...
     }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

and the error message I get is the normal -

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{url address}' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

The end result i'm looking for is to only allow HTTPS to access to API but first I need to get it to allow any origin... any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:asp.net-mvc6] header, this tag is reserved for a possible future version of the legacy ASP.NET MVC framework (based on MVC5). ASP.NET Core MVC is a complete rewrite and **not** compatible with the old ASP.NET MVC and uses the version 1.0 to make this incompatibility more obvious

Answer (score 0):

*facepalm* nothing to do with the cors that was fine... forgot to register one of my services.... note to self: dont dev late at night

Comment: That's because the error middleware clears all headers set by the CORS middleware, when an exception occurs